Configuring HAProxy for Redis PubSub
I'm trying to configure a HAProxy instance for a Redis cluster. The application that connects to Redis use both short-lived connections for common commands like SET/GET and long-lived connections for PubSub usage.
I struggle to find a good configuration for the timeouts. I would like to have a relatively short timeout for all commands (currently 2 hours) except for PubSub. The problem is that the long connections are impacted by the same timeouts so the PubSub connections drop after 2h.
The configuration currently looks like this:
frontend redisXfarm_frt
    bind XX.XX.XX.XXX:6379
    mode tcp
    timeout client 2h
    option tcpka
    maxconn 4000
    default_backend redisXfarm_bk

backend redisXfarm_bk
    balance first
    option tcp-check
    timeout server 2h
    tcp-check connect
    tcp-check send info\ replication\r\n
    tcp-check expect string role:master
    tcp-check send QUIT\r\n
    tcp-check expect string +OK
    fullconn 4000
 
    server redisX:XX.XX.XX.YYY:6379 XX.XX.XX.YYY:6379 maxconn 4096 check inter 10s
    server redisX:XX.XX.XX.ZZZ:6379 XX.XX.XX.ZZZ:6379 maxconn 4096 check inter 10s

I implemented some code to send tcpkeepalive packets otherwise the firewall would also drop the connection. Is there any way to make HAProxy aware of those tcpkeepalive packets? I tried to do so by adding option tcpka but it doesn't seem to do what I want (I guess it only forwards the tcpkeepalive packets to Redis)
